# Vue-CLI project automatic deployment on Firebase Hosting using GitHub actions

Tags: firebase, vue.js, continuous-integration, vue-cli, npm-ci

So I am having my Vue-CLI project and I can't manage automatic deployments.

I've been googling all day, I got the key from `firebase login:ci` but I don't understand where am I supposed to place it inside of a `yaml` files.
[image: The error]

I did add the FIREBASE_TOKEN as an environment variable to my github repo, but the problem persists. Even if firebase docs said `Option 1: Store the token as the environment variable FIREBASE_TOKEN. Your system will automatically use the token.`

Here's my `YAML` file, generated by firebase-CLI.

[image: yaml]

I can clone, push, fetch, create, delete and do whatever I want with my repos. Manual deploy works just fine.

Automatic deploy (on another repo, I am using Nuxt.js there) is working just fine out of the box.

Why am I having so much troubles with Vue-CLI?.. And how to fix this?

UPD: Here's output of `git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/mattboldt/typed.js.git` and it seems there's no errors while executing this command. And now I am even more confused... I don't even know WHERE'S the problem...
I also did commit changes to another repo (Nuxt.js) and automatic deployment did work over there. I also made sure that Firebase Service accounts are 100% identical between the Nuxt.js project and Vue-CLI. And it still doesn't work.
[image: ls-remote -h -t]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like StackOverflow is the best rubber duck ever.

So here's how I solved this issue:

`firebase-hosting-merge.yml`:
REPLACED

```
- run: npm ci && npm run build
```

With following code:

```
      - run: /usr/bin/git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
```

So basically replacing `ssh://` with `https://`

And then Hallelujah![image: 40 attempts]
I can't believe I spent the whole day figuring out ONE line of code...
However the issue is solved and I hope my experience will help somebody else ;)